# Invisible backslash in Javascript

Tags: javascript

It might be a stupid question, but I really need to know. Why JS doesn't see a single backslash?

For example:

```
console.log("\");
```

Gives me nothing, but when I add one more backslash, then it shows"\".

Why is that?

Comment: Backslash in string is used to escape the following symbol. To use it escape it by adding one more backslash

Comment: Actually, it doesn't give you nothing, it gives you a syntax error...

Comment: Emm no, it not gives syntax error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\ is an escape character. Refer to the article: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

There are some reserved single character escape sequences for use in strings:

```
\b: backspace (U+0008 BACKSPACE)
\f: form feed (U+000C FORM FEED)
\n: line feed (U+000A LINE FEED)
\r: carriage return (U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN)
\t: horizontal tab (U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION)
\v: vertical tab (U+000B LINE TABULATION)
\0: null character (U+0000 NULL) (only if the next character is not a decimal digit; else it’s an octal escape sequence)
\': single quote (U+0027 APOSTROPHE)
\": double quote (U+0022 QUOTATION MARK)
\\: backslash (U+005C REVERSE SOLIDUS)
```

Answer (score 0):

\ is the escape character in javascript hence why you can't see it when there's only one, if there's 2 the first one will escape the second one, this also works for stuff like(",',&)